# Salesforce Flow limitations

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

I have a flow where i want when the "Campaign Status" changes, to create new Campaign Member Status records and also update the Status of each Campaign Member. Some Campaigns have 80.000 Members. Will this be a problem for the flow? Also, as an alternative, should Batch Apex be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some Campaigns have 80.000 Members. Will this be a problem for the flow?

Yes, most definitely. The DML Rows limit is 10,000 in a transaction.

> Also, as an alternative, should Batch Apex be used instead?

Yes. Batch Apex is the only reasonable way for you to perform this kind of update at volume.

---

As an aside, this sounds like a non-best-practice use of the Status fields. If you're using the Campaign Member Status for something *other than* the individual status of each Campaign Member, you may wish to use a custom formula field instead to pull down a value from the parent Campaign.

Comment: David, thank you very much for your answer.